# Structure of "as in"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

When I ask question by using examples, they often use "***as in your example X***" If they confirm my examples . Is it some kind of reduced phrase? or "as in" means "for example" ?

For instance:

Me: Can I use this structure in my sentences? And I give my examples.

Someone answering my question: Yes, you could use this structure, ***as in the sentence 3***.

(Is this reduced phrase from something like this "***as you used in the sentence 3***" or just means "***for example in the sentence 3***")

Comment: ... as [it is presented] in the sentence 3.

Comment: ***The*** *sentence 3* is very awkward. It would normally just be *as in sentence 3* (no article) or *as in the third sentence*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Hi, is that usage of "as in" in my question the same as ***this usage*** of it? (Here is the link to the usage I meant by the marked phrase: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332301/correct-use-and-best-definition-of-as-in)

Comment: *As in* and *this usage of* mean *roughly* the same thing, although sentences that use them would need to be constructed differently (you can't simply replace one with the other)—and both sentences would need to mention two different things in order to achieve the same some kind of comparison.